# GMap.Net location on marker centralizes over point not above

Tags: winforms, .net-4.0, gmap.net

I have just started using GMAP.Net and I'm Setting a custom Marker thus:

```
 marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(Convert.ToDouble(latlon[0]), Convert.ToDouble(latlon[1])), new Bitmap(Iconpath));
```

where Iconpath points to a 42 * 38 pixel image of type PNG.

however the image appears central and immediately above the point being set by the above. What I would like is to know how to set it so the center of the image in over the location.

Any idea how to do that?

this is in a winforms .Net 4.0 application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found there was an easy way to do this thus:

```
                    Bitmap imgMarker = new Bitmap(Iconpath);
                marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(Convert.ToDouble(latlon[0]), Convert.ToDouble(latlon[1])), imgMarker);
                marker.Offset = new Point(imgMarker.Width/2,  imgMarker.Height / 2);
```

hope it helps someone else!

Comment: I needed to make the x / y values in the offset negative. But then it worked a treat for me.

Answer (score 0):

The GoogleMarker class seems to be designed for push pin looking images, where you would want the pin tip to be directly above the point of interest. Your best bet is to inherit the marker class and make your own class where you can control the image placement. Like this:

```
class customImageMarker: GMapMarker
{
    Bitmap Bitmap;

    public customImageMarker(PointLatLng p, Bitmap Bitmap)
     : base(p)
      {
         this.Bitmap = Bitmap;
         Size = new System.Drawing.Size(Bitmap.Width, Bitmap.Height);
         Offset = new Point(-Size.Width / 2, -Size.Height / 2);
      }

    public override void OnRender(Graphics g)
    {
        g.DrawImage(Bitmap, LocalPosition.X - Offset.X, LocalPosition.Y - Offset.Y, Size.Width, Size.Height); 
    }
}
```

Now just call your class:

```
marker = new customImageMarker(new PointLatLng(Convert.ToDouble(latlon[0]), Convert.ToDouble(latlon[0])), new Bitmap(Iconpath));
```

You can control the placement of the icon by adjusting the Offset variable.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a go on Sunday when I'm back. Is google similar to GMap.Net?

Comment: Hi i have tried this but I get the following error "Cannot implicitly convert type CustomImageMarker to GMap.Net.WindowsForms.Markers.GMarkerGoogle"

Comment: You have to initially define the marker as a customImageMarker and then you can add it to the layer as you typically would. Regardless, it looks like you found a much easier way!